# Duda de la aplicación Python

Tags: base-de-datos

¿Cuáles son los comandos para crear una resta, suma, multiplicacióny división en la aplicación de Python?

Comment: Hola user326513, bienvenido, **4 - 2** resta, **4 + 2** suma, **4 * 2** multipĺica y **4 / 2** divide, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html